# Accessing a custom queryset in a django template for-loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to loop over a queryset in a Django template like so:

```
{% for thing in things %}
//Do stuff
{% endfor %}
```

But I do not want to loop over all my "things", but rather a subset of them.
Lets say my things-model has a charfield "color". Now I only want to loop over things where the color is not None.
I would now create a custom queryset in my models like so:

```
def colored_things(self):
   return things.objects.filter(color__isnone=False)
```

But if I go back into my template to loop over my colored things, it behaves as if it would be empty ( the {% empty %} part of my for loop is fired).

```
{% for thing in things %}
//Do stuff
{% empty %}
{% endfor %}
```

So what do I need to do to access my custom queryset (created in models, but I can put it somewhere else if it helps) in my templates?

Comment: just make it as a property and use in your template

Comment: Your question is not clear. What class is `colored_things` a method on? And how are you calling that method? How are you passing the result to the template?

Comment: colored_things is a method in the things-model. @Daniel I guess that is my question. How do I pass the results to my template? I thought I can access them by just calling the method in the for loop. I tried it as a property, it behaves the same way as the method

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could use `@property` or `@cached_property` in your model, define a custom model manager or custom QuerySet. Without at least a rudimentary example of your model and your view it's hard to provide an accurate answer. Your method `colored_things` makes no sense as it is. We can't see where `things` come from and what it is. Eventually you wanted to write `self.objects...`.

Comment: let's put it this way... are you using Class Based Views or regular views so we know how you passed the variables to the template. Because really `colored_things` would be if on a result from the model `one = Color.objects.get(id=1)` then `not_colored = one.colored_things()` not logical and I'd just do the query from the view anyway since it's not pertaining to results based on the model instance itself.

Answer (score 1):

Add (if you don't have already) a get_context method to your model and add a context property containing the filter.
I would look somehting like this:

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(THINGS-MODEL, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context['colored_things'] = THINGS-MODEL.objects.filter(color__isnone=False)
    return context
```

now in your template, you can loop over `colored_things` containing the filtered data you set before in the get_context method.

Comment: I deleted that comment, as it became obsolete with your edit. However the model has no `get_context` method. You were probably thinking the view, because class based views have that method. This would work fine if the OP uses CBV, which he unfortunately didn't reveal in his question.